# Spring JPA not in

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two class `Drug` and `medicalDrawer`.

I search a way to get all `medicalDrawer` not used in `Drug`

```
@Entity
public class Drug {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long drugId;

    @OneToOne
    private MedicalDrawer medicalDrawer;
}

@Entity
public class MedicalDrawer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long medicalDrawerId;

    private String name;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion - `GenerationType.AUTO` is NOT suitable for production-grade applications. It should only be used for running experiments on local environment.

Comment: not related to the question...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using Spring and JPARepository, it supports quite a lot keywords like : 'And', 'IsNull',  similarly  'NotIn'.

Check this out: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Now, coming to your question, here is my approach:

1. Get all the drugs using findAll(), loop through and add      medicalDrawerId in a list say medicalDrawerDrugList.
2. Find MedicalDrawer, which are not in drugs. For that, you can 
       write something like this:

   ```
    findByMedicalDrawerIdNotIn(medicalDrawerDrugList);
   ```

I hope, this helped.